# Why do we need to run unbuffered channels in go routine but buffered channels can work without go routine?

Tags: go

I was going through tutorials on gobyexample. I noticed the author has shown example of gochannel using go routine but in buggered go channel he is directly sending messages to channel .

I tried on my local system to run unbuffered channel without go routine but it is throwing "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!"
but buffered channels are working fine without go routine

```
func channelDemo() {
    message := make(chan string)
    // go func() {
    //  message <- "Hello"
    // }()
    message <- "Hello"
    msg := <-message

    fmt.Println("msg", msg)
}
func channelBufferingDemo() {
    messages := make(chan string, 3)

    messages <- "Buffered"
    messages <- "channel"
    fmt.Println(<-messages)
    fmt.Println(<-messages)
}
```

Comment: You can use buffered and unbuffered channels both with and without goroutines. You just use whichever you need for the use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A channel send will succeed only if the channel can accept the input, that is, either there's a listener for that channel, or there is available buffer in the channel. Otherwise goroutine will go to sleep until one of those become true: either someone starts listening, or someone reads from the channel and there is now buffer space.

With a channel with no buffer, the only way you can write to it is if someone is listening to it. If there is only one goroutine and if you write to the channel, all goroutines will be asleep.

With a channel with buffer size 3 and one goroutine, you can write to if 3 times without reading from it. The 4th write will put all goroutines to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

> buffered channels are working fine without go routine

because they won't block until their buffer is full. 
Which is what happens in `channelBufferingDemo`. It has a length of 3, you write twice on it, it is not full, thus the program keeps going on, you read twice on it, it dequeues and let the program finish.

In `channelDemo` the channel does not have a buffer, so the first time you read or write, it blocks until another routine performs the opposite operations.
Because in your example you are running both operations sequentially within the same routine, it inevitably block, ending with this fatal error.